# Erro JPA+HIBERNATE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Senhores.
Tenho uma classe chamada Usuario.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_usuario")
public class Usuario {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String email;

@Column(name = "senha", nullable = false, length = 32)
private String senha;

@Column(name = "hash_md5", nullable = false, length = 32)
private String hashMD5Email;

@Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
private int ativo = 0;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuario",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//@JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario")
private List consultas ;

@Column(name = "data_cadastro", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Calendar dataCadastro;

public Usuario() {

}


public void setDataCadastro(Calendar dataCadastro) {
    this.dataCadastro = dataCadastro;
}

public Calendar getDataCadastro() {
    return dataCadastro;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

public void setAtivo(int ativo) {
    this.ativo = ativo;
}

public int getAtivo() {
    return ativo;
}


public List getConsultas() {
    return consultas;
}


public void setConsultas(List consultas) {
    this.consultas = consultas;
}
```

Tenho também uma classe chamada ‘ConsultaTratadaHtml’, segue o código da mesma.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_consulta")
public class ConsultaTratadaHtml {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "consulta_html", nullable = false, length = 500)
private String consultaHtml;

@Column(name = "data_consulta", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Calendar dataConsulta;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="id_usuario",nullable = false)
private Usuario usuario;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getConsultaHtml() {
    return consultaHtml;
}

public void setConsultaHtml(String consultaHtml) {
    this.consultaHtml = consultaHtml;
}

public Calendar getDataConsulta() {
    return dataConsulta;
}

public void setDataConsulta(Calendar dataConsulta) {
    this.dataConsulta = dataConsulta;
}

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}
}
```

Como é possivel perceber a classe Usuario tem um relacionamento oneToMany com a classe ConsultaTratadaHtml. E a classe ConsultaTratadaHtml tem um relacionamento ManyToOne com a classe Usuário. Ou seja temos um relacionamento bidirecional, sendo que a chave fica na classe ConsultaTratadaHtml. Estou tentando salvar uma nova ConsultaTratadaHtml usando o seguitne código :

```
Usuario usuario = new UsuarioDAO().buscarUsuarioByEmail("pedro@gmail");

    ConsultaTratadaHtml consulta = new ConsultaTratadaHtml();

    consulta.setConsultaHtml("teste de persistencia");
    consulta.setDataConsulta(Calendar.getInstance());               

    consulta.setUsuario(usuario);
    usuario.getConsultas().add(consulta);

    new ConsultaTratadaHtmlDAO().salvarConsulta(consulta);
```

Mas gera um erro na seguinte linha :

```
usuario.getConsultas().add(consulta);
```

A seguinte mensagem de erro

```
Exception in thread “main” org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:     br.com.pedrodev.webservicecpf.domain.Usuario.consultas, could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:582)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:201)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:561)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.write(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:392)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.add(PersistentBag.java:297)
at testes.Programa.main(Programa.java:39)
```

Alguém tem idéia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc precisa entender o carregamento de listas por JPA, vc pode ter uma ideia melhor [neste link](http://blog.caelum.com.br/entendendo-o-lazy-e-o-eager-load-da-jpa/)

Vc precisa adicionar o `fetch` para que a lista seja completamente carregada

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuario",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List consultas ;
```

O carregamento completo de listas pode gerar problemas de memoria, então vc deve ter cuidado ao usar.
 Outra alternativa é ativar o proxy da transação, se estiver usando Spring basta adicioanr `@Transactional` sobre o metodo, que ele habilitará o proxy

Fonte:https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822283/4395789